# Duplicate rows in sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, duplicates, primary-key

I have android app with local sqlite database but I have problem with duplicate row. Every time when I start app,  are addding items to db but some item with the same id already exist there. Problem is I cannot update/rewrite rows which has the same id. This is my db: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1cc6gvned02ioxn/sql.png)

Declarations:

```
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "foodsDB";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_FOODS = "tableFoods";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_FOODNAME = "food_name";
private static final String KEY_ALERGEN_NO = "alergen_numbers";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
private static final String KEY_FOOD_NUMBER = "food_number";
```

DB create table:

```
  // Creating Table
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_FOODS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FOODS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " TEXT,"  + KEY_FOODNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ALERGEN_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_FOOD_NUMBER + " INTEGER"+")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_FOODS_TABLE);
}
```

DB insert:

```
 // Adding new food
void addFood(FoodsDB food) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, food.getID());
    values.put(KEY_FOODNAME, food.getFoodName());
    values.put(KEY_ALERGEN_NO, food.getAlergenyNumbers());
    values.put(KEY_DATE,food.getDate());
    values.put(KEY_FOOD_NUMBER,food.getFoodNumber());

    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        long rowId = db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_FOODS, null, values);
        if (rowId == -1) {
            // insertion failed
            String whereClause = KEY_DATE;
            //String[] whereArgs = new String[] {values.getAsString(KEY_DATE)};
            db.update(TABLE_FOODS, values, whereClause, null);
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

Any idea why I have more rows with the same id in DB? I also try set id to primary key but this not work.

Comment: Set `KEY_ID` as `PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT` and also check your  `db.update(.....)` method. I dont think this is correct.

Comment: 1. I dont understand why I need AI when my id is TEXT not INT atc and second when I set id to primary key and run app again I get SQLiteConstraintException: column id is not unique

Comment: but after changing this you must reinstall your app

Comment: yes I reinstall app I also try manualy remove db file from data but when app try add new row which has the same id I get SQLiteConstraintException: column id is not unique.

Comment: but why you added data with same id? Primary key defined so that it's Unique

Comment: yes this is problem. Im adding many items to db and some items have the same id and there i need if the item with this ID already exist in table rewrite/update this item else add this item